# System shuts down abruptly after waking up

Tags: suspend, shutdown, power

I have recently installed Loki on Dell Inspiron 7560 (i7) laptop with 8 GB of RAM and 4 GB of Swap.
The system works fine for most of the time but when waking up after sleep and plugging in/out makes the system abruptly going out of power and shutting down. I have a dual boot system with windows and this problem is not there when I work boot windows.

I have checked a lot of solutions.

- I have gone to my BIOS power management where I enabled optimized for charging option.
- I have Swap space (4GB)
- I had installed `tlp`, but uninstalled it, thinking it might be interfering with the drivers.
- I have latest NVIDIA proprietary software (381.09) installed on my system, but my primary graphics card is Intel only.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Is it a manufacturing/hardware issue?

Comment: i am having the same problem except mine is installed on an iMac

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this type of problem on a number of different systems, but after a lot of work I tracked it down to the lid being opened (after suspend) not being recognised.  The fix was simple in the end, just add the following to you kernel parameters

```
button.lid_init_state=open
```

Basically this tells ACPI to emit an extra open event when waking from suspend which should stop the system shutting down.

For GRUB

Press e when the menu shows up and add this open to the end of the linux line:

linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff quiet splash

Press Ctrl+x to boot with these parameters.

For a general documentation about how to pass kernel parameters have a look at the always awesome Arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however, it'll help others if you give the whole set of instructions. If someone wants to dig deeper then they can go to the Arch wiki.

Comment: Also, I am not using eOS anymore, so I can't test it. If this solution works for anyone then kindly comment; I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: I was trying to keep the answer generic, I didn't want to just cut and paste from the archi wiki - but am happy to.  Do you have the issue with other linux distros on the same machine ?

Comment: Not really. I moved to Manjaro where I faced another issue, but it ironed out after few updates.